# Permission denied even though I am the admin?

Tags: 18.04, permissions

I have searched and searched and cannot seem to find this so I apologize if it ends up being a duplicate. I am running Ubuntu 18.04 and I keep running into an issue in my files where I do not have permission to open or delete files. I am the administrator and root, but I can't delete unnecessary programs under my own account. Is there any way to fix this or at least work around it? 
I have tried deleting these programs from bash and apt just says it can't find the files. 
Thanks in advance

As requested, here is the stuff I ran and the outputs asked for:

after I realized apt was not useful for this, I tried using nautilus

```
annie@dalek:/media/annie/56681DD6681DB629/Documents and Settings/{myname}/Downloads$ nautilus remove LoggerPro3_15.exe
```

This resulted in some errors

```
(nautilus:27752): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 20:10:50.315: gtk_widget_show: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed

** (nautilus:27752): CRITICAL **: 20:10:50.315: setup_side_pane_width: assertion 'priv->sidebar != NULL' failed

** (nautilus:27752): WARNING **: 20:10:50.628: Unable to get contents of the bookmarks file: Error opening file /root/.gtk-bookmarks: No such file or directory

** (nautilus:27752): WARNING **: 20:10:50.629: Unable to get contents of the bookmarks file: Error opening file /root/.gtk-bookmarks: No such file or directory
```

I don't know why it can't find the file..

Here's the output for ls -la

```
total 1291297
drwxrwxrwx 1 annie annie      4096 Jan 26 01:31 .
drwxrwxrwx 1 annie annie      8192 Jan 28 18:49 ..
-rwxrwxrwx 1 annie annie       282 Jan 26 01:31 desktop.ini
-rwxrwxrwx 2 annie annie 467208096 Oct  9 17:35 LoggerPro3_14_1.exe
-rwxrwxrwx 2 annie annie 479687376 Jun  2  2019 LoggerPro3_15.exe
-rwxrwxrwx 2 annie annie   1573568 Jan 13 21:04 SteamSetup.exe
-rwxrwxrwx 2 annie annie 363042960 Dec 29 13:06 TINspireCXCASStudentSoftware-5.1.0.177.exe
-rwxrwxrwx 2 annie annie  10748145 Dec 29 13:05 TI-Nspire_CX_SS_Guidebook_EN.pdf
```

Comment: Please provide a clear, real-life example that we can help you troubleshoot.

Comment: I have been going to Program Files (x86) to delete LoggerPro3_15.exe (that's a whole other story) so I can redownload it. I never have the option to move to trash and if I manually move it to trash, I get a popup saying I have "insufficient permissions"
In bash, I run sudo apt remove LoggerPro3_15.exe and get
E: Unable to locate package LoggerPro3_15.exe
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'LoggerPro3_15.exe'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'LoggerPro3_15.exe'

Comment: Apt is a package manager, not a file manager. It can only install/remove packages. It cannot delete random files. "*Could not find any package...*" is the expected and correct behavior. Stop trying to use apt for that purpose.

Comment: Do you know the full path to LoggerPro3_15.exe ?

Comment: Have you tried to "force" it with `rm -f LoggerPro3_15.exe"?

Comment: @user535733 I know the full path. I also realized I'm dumb for using apt, but idk what else to do then. I have not had to do this in awhile and I have forgotten everything I once knew.

Comment: @zx485 that didn't work

Comment: @misterkawhat please use the [edit] button to add the exact command(s) you tried and complete error messages to your question

Comment: Also show us the complete output of `ls -la` for the directory containing LoggerPro3_15.exe

Comment: That looks like an external drive. You may just need to remount the drive with read write permission but the answer may be more complicated if this is a Windows drive. Please include the output of `lsblk -f` Please reply back with @mchid at the beginning of the message so I will get a notification. Thanks!

Comment: My `pathlld` script ( https://github.com/waltinator/pathlld.git ) nay help.

Comment: @mchid 
    ~~~
    NAME FSTYPE LABEL UUID     MOUNTPOINT 
    loop0 squashf                              /snap/core18/1650 
    loop1 squashf                              /snap/gtk-common-th 
    loop2 squashf                              /snap/gtk-common-th 
    loop3 squashf                              /snap/gnome-system- 
    loop4 squashf                              /snap/sololearn/27 
    loop5 squashf                              /snap/gtk2-common-t 
~~~
Too many characters for one comment

Comment: loop6  squashf      /snap/eclipse/40
loop7  squashf      /snap/sololearn/26
loop8  squashf      /snap/gtk2-common-t
loop9  squashf      /snap/spotify/36
loop10 squashf     /snap/core/8592
loop11 squashf     /snap/gnome-charact
loop12 squashf     /snap/pycharm-educa
loop13 squashf     /snap/libreoffice/1
loop14 squashf     /snap/core/8689
loop15 squashf     /snap/gnome-3-28-18
loop16 squashf     /snap/gnome-calcula
loop17 squashf     /snap/gnome-charact
loop18 squashf     /snap/pycharm-educa
loop19 squashf     /snap/gnome-logs/61
loop20 squashf     /snap/kde-framework

Comment: loop21 squashf     /snap/gnome-system-
loop22 squashf     /snap/blender/36
loop23 squashf     /snap/gimp/227
loop24 squashf     /snap/gnome-3-28-18
loop25 squashf     /snap/spotify/41
loop26 squashf     /snap/gimp/245
loop27 squashf     /snap/gnome-calcula
loop28 squashf     /snap/gnome-logs/81
loop29 squashf     /snap/blender/35
loop30 squashf     /snap/core18/1668
loop31 squashf    /snap/libreoffice/1

Comment: sda                                                          
├─sda1 ntfs    Recovery 7EE21541E214FED9                     
├─sda2 vfat    0E17-74A6         /boot/efi
├─sda3                                                       
└─sda4 ntfs    56681DD6681DB629     /media/annie/56681D
sdb                                                          
├─sdb2 vfat     0025-B082                            
└─sdb3 ext4    67880f53-90b3-4353-b723-59edec78931c /